# How to put headers in tile list?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I dont want to make hboxes with labels and all for static headers in tile list... IS there a shortway to put column headers in a tile list in flex easily?

Thanks

Comment: Wrap it in a Panel? Sorry you are a bit vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `TileList` isn't meant to work like a `DataGrid` and doesn't have support for column headers. It's layout is meant to be fluid based on the size of your renderer and the dimensions of the `TileList` itself. If you want to put headers above the items in your `TileList`, you'll have to place it inside a container like a `Canvas` or `VBox` and position the header labels manually.

Comment: That is what I was wondering. Well I did it by adding a horizontalList for header. But I still wonder, what is special with tilelist that we can not implement in datagrid (with item renderers of course). Thanks.

Comment: @user503510, A `TileList` won't have as large an overhead compared a `DataGrid`. A `DataGrid` has extra functionality to support sortable/dragable columns, etc. which may not need. You can get the same kind of functionality using a `DataGrid` and an itemRenderer, but the overhead/hassle just isn't worth it in my opinion. I hope my answer helped. If you have any more questions, just let me know. :)

Comment: It certainly did Jason. Thanks. You are one of the very few Flex Gurus in here :-)